# SharedPreference Remove when we exit the application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to remove sharedPreference details;I did like this, but not working:

```
SharedPreferences  myRoutes = this.getSharedPreferences("myDefalutRoute", MODE_PRIVATE);
public void onExitAction(View botton){
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
    finish();    

    SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myLogedPrefs",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    myPrefs.edit().remove("myLogedPrefs");
    myPrefs.edit().clear(); 
    myPrefs.edit().commit();

    myRoutes.edit().remove("myDefalutRoute");
    myRoutes.edit().clear(); 
    myRoutes.edit().commit();

    moveTaskToBack(true);

}
```

After exit the application & go to data\data\package\myLogedPrefs.xml contain values.

How we can remove the SharedPreferences data?

Please help me..

Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure onExitAction() is being called?   Where are you calling it from.   Put in some logging to make sure it's being called.  And as J_Andr mentioned, you probably want to move this code or call the function from the onDestroy method of the initial Activity of the application.

Comment: Thanks for help.Should I put in the Initial page onDestroy()?

Comment: Yes - whatever Activity you've defined as your main in your manifest.

Answer (score 3):

```
@override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myfile",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    myPrefs.edit().remove("myfile");
    myPrefs.edit().clear(); 
    myPrefs.edit().commit();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting those removal commands into onDestroy().